# Change SQL Server 2000 from Active/Active to Active/Passive

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, clustering, high-availability

I know it's cringe-worthy to use this term, but I have a SQL Server 2000 cluster with one clusetered instance running on it with multiple resources running on one of the two servers in the cluster all the time.

For legacy licensing purposes, we'd like to change this cluster from "active/active" to "active/passive" to save on two Enterprise licenses - they only run on one server anyways.

Microsoft Premier support politely told to me to fly a kite.  Does anyone have any links or resources on how to do this?
Any help would be appreciated

From a licensing perspective, I don't want to pay for 4 Enterprise SQL Server licenses. I want everything running on one node at a time so I only have to pay for 2 Enterprise SQL Server licenses.

Comment: Are you not simply referring to migrating databases from one instance to another, then just removing one instance?

Comment: What version OS is the cluster running on?

Comment: @Dave Harding Refer the below links which I think it might help you :) http://www.techrepublic.com/article/build-your-skills-test-sql-server-2000-clustering-in-vmware/ ,http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Installation/stepbystepclustering/356/

Comment: SQL Server 2000 hasn't been supported for a while... no wonder they didn't give you support. I don't understand your question though you have a single clustered instance so you aren't using both. Could you clarify your question with the correct beginning and end state?

Comment: My apologies for not being familiar with the correct nomenclature.  From what I can see, there is only one instance of a database, along with its resources running on one node.  There are cluster groups: (Cluster Group, File server Group and SQL group).  I can move some resources onto one node, while leave other resource with the first node (which to me, sounds like active/active configuration).  What I would like is for everything to run on one node and only move to the second node in the event of failure (active/passive)

Comment: @PathumAnjana, thanks for the link. Very descriptive, but I don't see if there is a mechanism to configure the cluster to have all resources stay on one node and all move over to the other node in the event of failure.  I know, it's painfully obvious I'm not a DBA :)

Comment: @ShawnMelton, it's Server 2003 Enterprise.

Comment: @ShawnMelton, I want the resources to fail over to the second node in case there is a problem with the first node.  All or nothing.

Comment: What you are wanting to do has nothing to do with SQL Server. You need to configure the cluster resources to all have a preferred owner (node 1 if you will) and more importantly dependencies. When you configure the dependiences if one of those items fails over the dependent items will as well.

Comment: @ShawnMelton, thank you for that.  I will get on this and let you know ASAP.

Comment: @ShawnMelton, can you put your official answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can review this MSSQLTip to get more information on what `active/active` and `active/passive` mean in regards to SQL Server Clusters:
[SQL Server Clustering Active vs Passive](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1554/sql-server-clustering-active-vs-passive/)

In your situation, and based on your comments, the only thing you need to do is configure the dependencies for your resources. So if I have a cluster resource for the the SQL Server Cluster Name and it fails over, then all of the dependent resources will follow suite.

I have not messed with or ever configured a SQL Server 2000 cluster so I do not know what how this was done during installation. I am aware that starting with SQL Server 2005 the installation did more of this for you: [Failover cluster resource dependencies in SQL Server](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/835185)

Answer (score 0):

*Please note that I'm refraining from offering licensing advice due to [recent discussion](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/are-licensing-questions-within-our-scope) indicating that this probably isn't wise.*

Based on your comments, you have the following groups defined within Cluster Administrator:

- Cluster Group
- File Server Group
- SQL Group

Your "Cluster Group" probably includes a "Cluster IP Address", "Cluster Name", and "Physical Disk" (Quorum) resource. If so, this is unlikely to relate to SQL Server.

Your "File Server Group" probably includes a number of "File Share" resources. If so, it is unlikely to relate to SQL Server.

Your "SQL Group" probably includes an "IP Address", "SQL Server", "Network Name", and many "Physical Disk" resources (among other things).

If the above is true, then **only the SQL Group** is running any software that specifically relates to SQL Server. Because of the way Windows Clustering works, it's going to be running in an Active/Passive manner.

Whether this is the same as "Active/Passive" from a licensing perspective - especially when dealing with older versions of SQL Server - is a different matter entirely, and not something I can answer. You may need to verify this with Microsoft.